# Blackberry glossy tabbar

Tags: blackberry, tabs

I have a tab bar in my application, however I'm trying to attain a glossy effect like the one featured in the Rhapsody Blackberry app or the Flixster Blackberry app. I've thought about using a PNG, but I'm sure theres a better way to do it programmatically like using a gradient. Any help would be much appreciated!

Flixster app
http://news.cnet.com/i/bto/20091106/Flixter_Curve.png

Rhapsody app (I would prefer to have it look like this)
http://nexus404.com/Blog/wp-content/uploads2/2010/12/blackberry-for-rhapsody-300.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is indeed possible.

1. Create a 1 pixelx40pixel  (height as much as you want) png image of a gradient which is glossy so we get the glossy effect.
2. in `paint()` call `graphics.tileRop()` passing in `Graphics.ROP_SRC_COPY` as the Constant for the raster operation to execute.

This will draw the gradient to the extent of the region you set to.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is use PNG for that. If you try to paint gradient programmatically be ready to see non-smooth gradient with visible color lines.